# Capturar botones de un dialogo en un fragmento Android Studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una duda, he creado un dialogo personalizado de la siguiente manera:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:padding="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Existe una Nueva versión"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#F1F1F1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView28" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView29"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Actualizar para continuar"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_black"
        android:id="@+id/btnDismissUpdateVersion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Más tarde"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView29" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_black"
        android:id="@+id/btnUpdateVersion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Actualizar"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView29" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Tengo una **Clase** que me muestra ese cuadro de dialogo y al mismo tiempo disminuye el dialogo:

```js
package com.usuario.Utils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.usuario.R;

public class VersionDialog {

    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    public VersionDialog(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void startLoadingDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_version, null));
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void dismissDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

En la siguientes lineas de código estoy declarando y mostrando el dialogo pero aún no veo la forma de capturar los botones de dicho dialogo:

```js
class mapaInicio : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

  lateinit var versionDialog: VersionDialog
  lateinit var btnDismissUpdateVersion:Button
  lateinit var btnUpdateVersion:Button
  
  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //Mapbox.getInstance(requireContext() , getString(R.string.access_token))
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa_inicio, container, false)
    }
    
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
  versionEvansDialog = VersionEvansDialog(this.requireActivity())
  btnDismissUpdateVersion = view.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissUpdateVersion)
  btnUpdateVersion = view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateVersion)
  
  checkVersion(2)
  
  btnDismissUpdateVersion.setOnClickListener(this)
  btnUpdateVersion.setOnClickListener(this)
  }
  
  //Función donde comparo la versión para enviar el cuadro de dialogo
  private fun checkVersion(version:Int){
      if(version < 3){
          versionEvansDialog.startLoadingDialog()
      }
  }
  
  override fun onClick(v: View?) {
      if (v != null) {
          when(v.id){
              R.id.btnDismissUpdateVersion -> {
                  versionEvansDialog.dismissDialog()
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Me muestra el siguiente error:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: view.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissUpdateVersion) must not be null**

Si alguien me podría guiar un poco y ayudar le agradecería de antemano...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes obtener los botones al momento de crear la vista para tu dialogo, lo que haces es tratar de obtenerlos desde la vista de tu fragment por lo que obtienes un null.

Prueba modificando la clase de tu dialogo

```
public class VersionDialog {

private Context context;
private AlertDialog dialog;
//Agrega getters para acceder a tus botones desde el fragment
private Button update, dismissUpdate;

public VersionDialog(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
}

public void startLoadingDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_version, null);
    update=view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateVersion);
    dismissUpdate=view.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissUpdateVersion);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

public void dismissDialog(){
    dialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Comment: Gracias, en realidad estaba haciendo mal capturar los botones desde el fragmento, me sirvió mucho tu ayuda.